# how to read data from firebase database - value always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from the database and I can't. I've tried it in several ways, but I always pass a column of data, it gives "undefined"

```
// var contatos = firebase.database().ref().child('/contato').get().then((snapshot) => {
        //     if (snapshot.exists()) {
        //         console.log(snapshot.val().nome;
        //     } else {
        //         console.log("No data available");
        //     }
        // }).catch((error) => {
        //     console.error(error);
        // });

        firebase.database().ref('/contato').on("value", (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot.val().assunto)
        });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data at `contato` in your data (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.